# Proof of $(A+B) \times (A-B) = -2(A X B)$

Tags: vectors, cross-product

Proof of $(A+B) \times (A-B) = -2(A \times B)$, where 'A' and 'B' are vectors

Comment: What about said proof?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the distributive law,
$$(A+B)\times(A-B)=A\times A-A\times B+B\times A-B\times B$$
$$A\times A=B\times B=0$$
$$(A+B)\times(A-B)=0-A\times B+B\times A-0$$
$$B\times A=-A\times B$$
$$(A+B)\times(A-B)=-A\times B-A\times B=-2(A\times B)$$